# Looping through guild members with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been attempting to make a bot that will give all users in my small guild (<50 members) a role.
I have had a tough time getting the bot to loop through all of the users in the server.

Currently it will output:

```
02/06/21 17:09:23: Successfully gave john_doe#1234 DJ role. (1 users!).
02/06/21 17:09:23: user john_doe#2234 gave all (1) users DJ role. (placeholder1).
```

Any advice?

Here is the part of the code I am working on:

```
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "Give DJ ALL"):
        count = 0

        for member in message.guild.members:
            count = count + 1
            await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name = "DJ"))
            print(str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%x %X")) + ": " + "Successfully gave " + str(member) + " DJ role. (" + str(count) + " users!).")


        await message.channel.send("Successfully gave " + str(count) + " users DJ!")
        print(str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%x %X")) + ": " + "user " + str(message.author) + " gave all ("+ str(count) + ") users DJ role. (" + str(message.guild.name) + ").")
```

edit: yes i have enabled intents in my bot settings on the website
alonside this:

```
async def on_ready():
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.presences = True
    intents.members = True
```

Comment: Did you enable `intents.members`?

Comment: Yes I have enabled it in my discord dev portal bot settings.
And here:
```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.presences = True
    intents.members = True
```

Comment: You don't enable them like that, you're supposed to  pass the intents in the constructor, not inside an event

Comment: Thank you.
I have fixed this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using proper syntax thanks to Łukasz Kwieciński.

code here:

```py
client = discord.Client(intents = discord.Intents.all())
```